# Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent starts Music Player in background

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have an android app, which doesn't work with audio or music player, but it can take pictures from my custom wrapper around Camera class and from calling MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, but sometimes, when I try to open this intent my mediaplayer in background starts to play music! If I leave and enter this Intent again my music "pauses", so looks like switching to this Intent switches my music! Why does it happen?

here is how I start intent, just like in tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    releaseCameras(); //here I clear all reserved shared cameras
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your third-party camera app is doing that, in all likelihood. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: @CommonsWare but my wrapper was working nice without issues, unless I've added this intent call function to this class